# Why can't I remove the light blue weight paint from my mesh?

Tags: weight-painting

[image: view of vertices with a blue highlight]

I even maxed out my strength and everything but it still can't remove that light blue part of that mesh area. I need to reduce it back to normal dark blue.

Comment: maybe share this part of your mesh? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Weight paint gives the red-to-blue gradient that's irremovable as it's **not** a material.

Answer (score -1):

Add extra geometry and then subtract and then remove useless geometry.

Comment: Some more details perhaps? It's vague.